# Как объяснить правописание слова "пенсионный"?

Tags: орфография

*Пенсионный* написала с мягким знаком: *пеньсионный*.

Answer (score 2):

Правильное написание: *пенсия, пенсионный,* хотя сейчас эти слова произносятся по-разному: в слове *пенсия* Н произносится мсгко, а в слове *пенсионный* — твердо.  У звука Н в этих словах разная фонетическая позиция: возможно, на твердое произношение оказывает влияние звук О в слове *пенсионный*

Орфограмма, связанная с написанием мягкого знака в середине слова, касается пяти согласных З/С, Д/Т и Н, которые могут в некоторых сочетаниях взаимно смягчать друг друга, например: песня и пенсия, жизнь и вензель. Но Н перед З/С — это особый случай

Н перед  мягкими З/С может произноситься как МЯГКО (пенсия, гортензия, вензель), так и ТВЕРДО (пансионат, в линзе, вонзить), что  говорит об усилении позиции этого звука, то есть смягчение перестает быть обязательным.

Тем не менее, на письме сочетание  звуков Н и З/С среди остальных не выделяется, мягкий знак  в этих сочетаниях не пишется. Произношение конкретных слов на написание мягкого знака не влияет.

Это общая тенденция к уменьшению взаимного влияния согласных (например, в слове *ветви* раньше произносили мягкий звук Т, что видно из правил письма на эту тему). Также с словаре Аванесова 1985 года указывается  одинаковое мягкое произношение Н в словах *пенсия* и *пенсионный*, поэтому старшей нормой, вероятно, надо считать мягкое произношение.

А что нам говорят обычные ПРАВИЛА? Причину орфограммы они не называют и решение предлагают формальное, но оно вполне рабочее.

Например, проверяем Ь в слове *возьми*: возьми — возьму, звук М   становится твердым, а звук З остается мягким, поэтому мягкость его собственная, пишем Ь.

Проверяем мягкий звук Н в слово *вензель*. А как его проверить, если мягкий З находится в середине слова, твердым его не сделаешь. Но если нет провереи, то по правилу нет и мягкого знака.

Точно также нельзя подобрать проверку для слов *пенсия, пенсионный*, поэтому мягкость звука Н мягким знаком не обозначаем.

Answer (score 0):

Это заимствованное слово, причем во всех возможных языках-источниках мягкости у этого звука нет.
В таких случаях в русской орфографии мягкий знак обычно не используется (кроме разделительного, смыслоразличительного и в некоторых случаях - имен собственных).

Вообще вопрос о том, как читать и как писать заимствованные слова в части палатализованных (смягченных) согласных достаточно путаный. Даже в вопросе передачи согласных перед "смягчающими гласными" (Я, Ю, Ё не говоря уж о Е и И) есть некоторые сложности. Но наш случай относительно понятен, тем более что произношение [ньсь] стало нормативным сравнительно недавно.

Comment: behemothus:  _"…произношение [ньсь] стало нормативнім сравнительно недавно"_. === Что-то не то… Как минимум в отношении разбираемого слова. Орфоэпические словари мягкий [н'] в слове _пенсия_ считают **старшей** нормой, а твёрдый [н] — младшей.

Comment: @slava1947 - сие очень странно есть. А какого года старшая и младшая?!

Comment: И о каких словарях вообще речь идет?

Comment: Я слово "пенсия" с мягким "н" произношу и читаю, но "пенсионный" - с твёрдым. Возможно, сказывается положение ударения или похожесть на "пень". Вряд ли можно одно из другого выводить